# Don't include myself in the comment reply candidates popup list

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-replies

I just found by chance this behavior:

> [image]

I don't want myself listed in that popup. **Turns out it's happening only in Meta which means it's a bug, some change not yet deployed to all sites.**

Comment: A great catch by you! And that's exactly what I wanted to ask to the meta, but wasn't able to :( However, lets hope it gets to work..

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan why you weren't able to ask this on Meta before?

Comment: Because of an old mistake! I asked a question which was already asked and at that time I didn't know the terms of the site it was like the first day on Stack Overflow and since the very first week I am not able to ask any question. :( I have to point out many gaping holes in site, but can't do that. Lets see if I get a chance of it in future..:(

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan you mean you're question banned here on Meta? You can email the team asking to lift the ban, showing some answers you recently posted here. Can't see any real reason you deserve to stay banned. :)

Comment: Awww thanks alot for the support :) I will send an email staight away to them I hope they delete my questions to lift the ban..Thanks for the suggestion brother..

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan actually deleting your downvoted questions will only make you buried even deeper. They have their own way.

Comment: Yeah, I was mentioning them! So that they can remove this and help me get out of this situation..:)

Comment: Interestingly I'd quite like this to stay **and** work. There've been several times when i'd like to test the inbox by replying to myself (expecially with the new bar)

Comment: @RichardTingle what do you mean? I just tried, and I don't get any notification for such reply. (I do have sock for those purposes :))

Comment: I can reproduce it on meta, not on main.

Comment: @zch wow never thought to check... thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work currently,  I'd just *like* it to. Sockpuppets are a solution however

Comment: @Richard oh, I see now. Well, if they're not going to remove it guess it's better that it will cause actual notification! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a great clue by [zch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/207977/zch). Turns out the comments script had a dependency on some stuff in the old [top-bar](/questions/tagged/top-bar). Fixed with next meta build `%DATE%.1656`, since this only affects meta.

Comment: +1 for the juicy detail (dependency on the old top bar?! ;)) but fear no cigar yet: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk2Cv.png (rev 2013.11.18.1655) - maybe because I'm also the OP here?

Comment: forgot to change the _pasted_ version number, change still in the pipes... it was a very juicy bug though; and not the first of it's kind...

Comment: Glad to make your day interesting! :-P